# How to convert date range into whole number (integer) in SQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a date 2013-03-01 and date 2013-04-02. How do I get a integer value between that date, for example in this case 2 days. In SQL kindly advise how to construct the query

```
day_date             
---------------------
2005-07-29 00:00:00  
2013-03-01 00:00:00  
2013-04-02 00:00:00  
2013-06-01 00:00:00  
2013-10-19 00:00:00  
2013-10-23 00:00:00  
2013-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` function

Comment: Hint : [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp).

Comment: The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates. SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate

Answer (score 2):

The `DATEDIFF()` function returns the time between two dates.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

Comment: By why it doesn't count let say 2014-11-30 to 2014-11-30 as 1 day? how can i do that because i need to use this value to divide a total of something....so when i have 20 personnel on 2014-11-30 it will be counted as 20 because 20/1 but if i use datediff it will become 20/0 = 0 which is incorrect